# Navigate to a URL when auth completed succesfully

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, supabase

I am currently developing a project for learning purposes, using Angular16 and Supabase as the backend. I have succesfully managed to sign in users with Github, Google and email (technically it does not matter how I sign in since the problem is the same with every provider).

My problem is the following, I provide the code and then explain:

**login.component.ts**:

```
async signInWithGithub(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      this.loading = true;
      this.supabase.signInWithGithub()
      .then(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error instanceof Error) {
          alert(error.message);
        }
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.loading = false;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    } finally {
      this.loading = false;
    }
  }
```

This code should perform the navigation once the authentication has been successfully completed. What happens, however, is that the method performs the navigation first, and some time later, the authentication is completed and returns to the login component.

So my question is: How can I perform the navigation once authentication is complete?

I provide every single code I made myself, since supabase does almost everything for us.

**supabase.service.ts**:

```
signInWithGithub(): Promise<OAuthResponse>{
    return this.supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({ provider: 'github' });
  }
```

The main method `signInWithOauth()` also return a `Promise<OAuthResponse>`

**EDIT**
When I sign in with github (or any provider) it adds some queryparams to the URL and then the page refreshes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since signing in with a third party requires redirecting to their website for authentication you cannot handle the redirect using Angular code. The `.signInWithOAuth` method takes a `options` property which contains a `redirectTo` property that should be used to redirect you back to a particular page on your web app.

```
this.supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({ 
  provider: 'github', 
  options: { 
    redirectTo: 'http://example.com/login' 
  } 
})
```

Do note that the `redirectTo` take a full URL. Here is the [docs](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-signinwithoauth).

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. Can you provide the URL where you found it please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
async signInWithGithub(): Promise<void> {
try {
  this.loading = true;
  this.supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({ provider: 'github' })
  .then(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  })
  .finally(() => {
    this.loading = false;
  });
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceof Error) {
    alert(error.message);
  }
} finally {
  this.loading = false;
}
}
```

It's a bit of a shot in the dark, cuz promises are weird and wonderful little creatures. But I think it might be to do with the fact that you're working with nested promises. So I'm just removing the one layer of promise to see if it might be the cause :)

`signInWithGithub()` -> Promise

`signInWithOAuth()` -> Also a promise (I think. I'm not familiar with supabase)

Its basic documentation, but it did let my mind go in this direction

Check out this link. It has some simple examples on nested and chained promises
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-typescript-with-native-es6-promises#

Comment: Yeah, I agree promises are weird. In this case, everything I put inside the then() executes instantly and doesnt wait until the promise is resolved. Btw, your answer is basically the same since I am calling a service (created by me) which calls the original method and you are calling it directly, so the problem remains.

Comment: @AhmedSHA256 alternatively, maybe put the "await" keyword in front of that method you're using to call the service? Might just be sequencing it incorrectly . https://www.atatus.com/blog/introduction-to-async-await-in-typescript/#:~:text=async%2Fawait%20functionality%20adds%20a,the%20value%20of%20the%20function.

Comment: It doesnt work, I dont know why. It executes everything correctly, and then like 500ms later the page refreshes. Its like the promise is being resolved in order, but some time later it does something in the frontend. Kinda crazy

Comment: Maybe last ditch effort, just move the navigation code to the finally code block xD

Comment: Nope. I dont really know what is happening here tbh